# Anyone know what series this image belongs to?

Tags: identification-request

Could be anime, manga, or even a visual novel, I'm not sure.

[image: 7 people dressed in a military attire, hand drawn and in black and white]

Comment: where did you get this image? can you provide the link?

Answer (score 3):

The [original uncropped image](http://luscious.net/c/hentai_manga/pictures/album/dorei-kishi-1_63019/id/2611336/@_dorei_kishi_1___59) is from **Dorei Kishi 1 「奴隷騎士Ⅰ」**, a Fate/stay night hentai manga by the doujinshi circle KUSARI. On a [prior page](http://luscious.net/c/hentai_manga/pictures/album/dorei-kishi-1_63019/id/2611115/@_dorei_kishi_1___52) is printed

> 陵辱連鎖シリーズ＋オリジナルイラスト集

which translates to:

> Ryoujoku Rensa Series + Original Illustration Collection

Ryoujoku Rensa is another hentai manga by KUSARI, based on the 2005 eroge novel of the same title. It is clear that **the image is an original illustration**.